# Test that a function is called in a promise resolution

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

I m building an application in which I need to test that a callbackfunction has been called in promise resolution.

Actually, I have the following code :

```
const callbackRender = (httpResponse, response) => {
  if (httpResponse.content.content) response.send(httpResponse.content.content)
  else response.render(httpResponse.content.page)
}

const callback = (injector, route) => {
  return (request, response) => {
    const ctrl = injector.get(route.controller)
    const result = ctrl[route.controllerMethod](new HttpRequest())
    if (result.then) {
      result.then(res => {
        console.log('hey I m in !')
        callbackRender(res, response)
      })
    } else {
      callbackRender(result, response)
    }
  }
}
```

I need to test that the

```
result.then(res => {
        console.log('hey I m in !')
        callbackRender(res, response)
      })
```

is well called.

I have written this test using mocha and chai, and I m always having 0 time spy calls :

```
it('should call the callback render method when httpResponse is a promise', (done) => {
      const mock = sinon.mock(injector)
      const ctrl = new UserControllerMock()
      const routes = routeParser.parseRoutes()
      mock.expects('get').returns(ctrl)
      const spy = chai.spy(callbackRender)
      callback(injector, routes[3])(request, response)
      setTimeout(() => {
        expect(spy).to.have.been.called.once
        mock.verify()
        mock.restore()
        done()
      }, 0)
    })
```

NB : The log message in the promise resolve part if well called, and I can display it on the screen.

Any idea ?

Comment: Asynchronous code needs to be tested asynchronously.

Comment: Exactly what I did with setTimeout :o

Comment: Not quite... `setTimeout` isn't going to help you here (at least, not predictably). Your test needs to [wait for the resolved promise](http://chaijs.com/plugins/chai-as-promised/) before checking its `expect` statement.

Comment: I don't know how to get this working. I can't access the returned promise in my case

Answer (score 1):

Return your response, then you can call `then` in your test.

```
const callback = (injector, route) => {
  return (request, response) => {
    const ctrl = injector.get(route.controller)
    const result = ctrl[route.controllerMethod](new HttpRequest())
    if (result.then) {
      return result.then(res => {
        callbackRender(res, response)
      });
    } else {
      return Promise.resolve(callbackRender(result, response));
    }
  }
}
```

Your test:

```
it('should call the callback render method when httpResponse is a promise', (done) => {
      const mock = sinon.mock(injector)
      const ctrl = new UserControllerMock()
      const routes = routeParser.parseRoutes()
      mock.expects('get').returns(ctrl)
      const spy = chai.spy(callbackRender)
      callback(injector, routes[3])(request, response).then(() => {
          expect(spy).to.have.been.called.once
          mock.verify()
          mock.restore()
          done()
      });
  });
```

Although, you don't seem to be injecting callbackRender, so your spy might still not get called.

Comment: My context is a bit wider, I can't return a promise, because the callback you see ther with the request, response parameters (line 2) is in fact an express web server callback. It doesn't manage promises at all. But thanks for the reply :)

Comment: I don't understand why you can't return the promise, I return promises in express handlers often. Without it, your only option is to set a longer timeout, but that is error prone.